# Chinese Characters And Image Insertion In LaTeX 2.09

Tags: graphics, symbols, packages

I am working on my CV and have made the unfortunate decision to add a couple lines of Simplified Mandarin and an image to the document. While normally this is quite easy to do through the use of the `CJK` and `graphicx` packages, those are not supported in 2.09 and `MP_Res` has not been ported over from `\documentstyle` to `\documentclass`, so I am currently stuck. Any ideas on how I can go about doing one(1) or both of these things?

**Example Code:**

```
\documentstyle[hyperref, margin, line]{MP_Res}

\hypersetup{backref,pdfpagemode=Full,colorlinks=true,backref}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.00in}\addtolength{\textheight}{1.858in}

\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\emph}

\def\Cplusplus{{\rm C\raise.5ex\hbox{\small ++}}}
\def\CSharp{{\rm C\raise.5ex\hbox{\small \#}}}
% 'st' 'nd' 'rd' 'th' superscripts for numbers
\def\first{{\raise.5ex\hbox{\small st}}}
\def\second{{\raise.5ex\hbox{\small nd}}}
\def\third{{\raise.5ex\hbox{\small rd}}}
\def\fourth{{\raise.5ex\hbox{\small th}}}
\newcommand{\slfrac}[2]{\left.#1\middle/#2\right.}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
%\def\sectionfont{\bf}
%\renewcommand{title}{\Bf}

\begin{document}

\name{\textbf{My Name}}

\address{
1234 Address Lane, City, STATE 12453 \ \ \ \ \  (555) 555-5555 \ \ \ \ email@gmail.com  \hspace{1 cm} \vspace{-1 mm}
}

\begin{resume}

\section{\textsc{Education}}

\textbf{University Name} \hfill 2014 -- Present \\
Doctoral Candidate in Something Useful \hfill 3.787 GPA \\
\vspace{-17pt}

\textbf{University Name} \hfill 2009 -- 2014 \\
Bachelor of Science Generic Degree  \hfill 3.8 GPA \\

\section{\textsc{Professional Experience}}

\employer{Company Name}
\title{\textbf{Important Sounding Title}}
\location{City, STATE}
\dates{August 2014 -- Present}
\begin{position}
\begin{raggedright}
I did things and they gave me money for it. \\
\end{raggedright}
\scriptsize\emph{Reference: Some Dude -- theiremail@companyname.com}
\end{position}

\section{\textsc{Notable Presentations \\ And Awards}} %\includegraphics[width=1in]{Example QR Code.png}}

1st Place Oral Presentation, 8th World Congress of Research Stuff
\vspace{-12 pt}

\quad Hangzhou/Tonglu, People's Republic of China 
\vspace{-7 pt}

(杭州/桐庐-中华人民共和国) \hfill August 2016
\vspace{-7 pt}

Invited Research Presentation, Some Cool Laboratory
\vspace{-12 pt}

\quad Way Too Much Money University, STATE \hfill May 2016
\vspace{-7 pt}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current Output]

[image: Desired Output]

[Example QR Code](http://www.qrstuff.com/images/sample.png)

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Use a modern class for your document. If you cannot update `MP_Res` (whatever that is), just use one of the other options available.

Comment: don't use `\documentstyle` if the class has not been updated since 1993 then perhaps it isn't the best one to use (or you should be able to update it easily enough yourself)

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to use such an old version of LaTeX, you should definitely, definitely update. There are plenty of cv templates out there (personally, I use [cvtex](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex) by Dario Taraborelli).